# A que se refiere con clase abstracta?

Tags: c++

Tengo una practica y me leyendo me surgio la duda de que es una clase  abstracta?

Entonces mi duda es ... esa, que es o en que consiste una clase abstracta

Comment: Deberías hacer investigación online y concretar la pregunta con las partes que no entiendas sobre un clase abstracta. Tal y como está redactada la publicación, es demasiado amplia y no se ajusta bien al formato del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es una clase que está diseñada sólo como clase *padre* de las cuales se deben derivar clases *hijas*.

Se usa para representar aquellas entidades o métodos que después se implementarán en las clases derivadas, pero en sí no contiene ninguna implementación, solamente representa los métodos que se deben implementar.

Son útiles para definir interfaces, es decir, un conjunto de métodos que definen el comportamiento de un módulo determinado.

En `C++` los métodos de las clases abstractas se definen como funciones virtuales puras.

Ejemplo:

```
class Abstracta
{
 public:
    virtual int metodo() = 0;
};

class ConcretaA : public Abstracta
{
 public:
     int metodo()
     {
      //haz algo
      return foo () + 2;
     }
};

class ConcretaB : public Abstracta
{
  public:
     int metodo()
     {
         //otra implementación
         return baz () - 5;
    }
};
```

La clase **ConcretaA** es una implementación de la clase **Abstracta**, y la clase **ConcretaB** es otra implementación. Debe notarse que el = 0 es la notación que emplea `C++` para definir funciones virtuales puras.

Espero que resuelva tus dudas! Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: Esta respuesta se refiere a una clase virtual pura, no a una clase abstracta.

Answer (score 2):

Una clase abstracta es una clase que pretende representar de una forma abstracta cómo dice su nombre, y tiene la característica de que no se puede instanciar ningún objeto directamente de ella, por ejemplo tenemos una clase SerVivo, dentro de la cual tenemos una gran gama de posibilidades de objetos, sin embargo instanciar un objeto con esas características tan abstractas o básicas puede ser insuficiente, en vez de eso creamos otra clase llamada SerHumano que herede las características de la clase SerVivo y tenga las suyas propias.